# Json not looking pretty on nested query rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

heres my show action to display users

```
def show 
  manager = HiringManager.find(params[:id])
  candidates = manager.users.to_json(:include => [:experiences, :educations])
  render :json => { manager: manager, candidates: candidates }                   
end
```

and my HiringManager and Hire Models

```
class HiringManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hires
  has_many :users, through: :hires
end

class Hire < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hiring_manager
  belongs_to :user
end
```

it works quite alright but the json preview is not pretty
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not work alright. The problem is that you are double encoding the JSON. `candidates = manager.users.to_json(:include => [:experiences, :educations])` creates a JSON string.

When you pass that to `render json:` its treated as a string and not an object and the quotes are escaped.

Instead of `.to_json` you want to use [`.as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) which creates an array of hashes instead of a string.

```
def show 
  manager = HiringManager.find(params[:id])
  candidates = manager.users.as_json(include: [:experiences, :educations])
  render json: { manager: manager, candidates: candidates }                   
end
```